# How to compute sum of hierarchical child nodes in a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have the following data:

| child | parent | value | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First |  | 0 | 0 |
| Project 1 | First | 0 | 0 |
| Project 2 | First | 0 | 0 |
| Project 3 | First | 0 | 0 |
| Auto | Project 1 | 16 | 0 |
| Huis | Project 1 | 14 | 0 |
| Auto | Project 2 | 11 | 0 |
| Huis | Project 2 | 12 | 0 |
| Overig | Project 2 | 7 | 0 |
| Auto | Project 3 | 30 | 0 |

I am trying to calculate the sum of all children for each parent:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=["child", "parent", "value", 'total'],
    
    data=[
        ["First", "", 0, 0],
        ["Project 1", "First", 0, 0],
        ["Project 2", "First", 0, 0],
        ["Project 3", "First", 0, 0],
        ["Auto", "Project 1", 16, 0],
        ["Huis", "Project 1", 14, 0],
        ["Auto", "Project 2", 11, 0],
        ["Huis", "Project 2", 12, 0],
        ["Overig", "Project 2", 7, 0],
        ["Auto", "Project 3",30, 0], 
    ]
)


df['total'] = df.groupby(['parent', 'child'])['value'].cumsum()
df
```

My groupby and cumsum method do not lead to the desired result. The desired output is:

| child | parent | value | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First |  | 0 | 90 |
| Project 1 | First | 0 | 30 |
| Project 2 | First | 0 | 30 |
| Project 3 | First | 0 | 30 |
| Auto | Project 1 | 16 | 16 |
| Huis | Project 1 | 14 | 14 |
| Auto | Project 2 | 11 | 11 |
| Huis | Project 2 | 12 | 12 |
| Overig | Project 2 | 7 | 7 |
| Auto | Project 3 | 30 | 30 |

How can I do this?

Comment: Are there only three levels in your hierarchy?

Comment: No, this hierarchy can extend to much more levels.

Comment: Then you need some sort of recursion. `groupby` is not the function for this.

Comment: What about a double for-loop?

Comment: This won't work if you have an arbitrary depth. Can you provide an example with an extra level of hierarchy? Do you want to sum up to the leafs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by not_speshal, if there might be more than three levels of hierarchy, you need recursion:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=["child", "parent", "value", 'total'],
    
    data=[
        ["First", "", 0, 0],
        ["Project 1", "First", 0, 0],
        ["Project 2", "First", 0, 0],
        ["Project 3", "First", 0, 0],
        ["Auto", "Project 1", 16, 0],
        ["Huis", "Project 1", 14, 0],
        ["Auto", "Project 2", 11, 0],
        ["Huis", "Project 2", 12, 0],
        ["Overig", "Project 2", 7, 0],
        ["Auto", "Project 3",30, 0],
    ]
)

def calculate_total(df, parent):
    children = df[df['parent'] == parent]
    
    total = 0
    for _, row in children.iterrows():
        child_total = calculate_total(df, row['child'])
        total += row['value'] + child_total

    df.loc[df['child'] == parent, 'total'] = total + df.loc[df['child'] == parent, 'value']
    return total

calculate_total(df, 'First')

print(df)
```

Output:

| child | parent | value | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First |  | 0 | 90 |
| Project 1 | First | 0 | 30 |
| Project 2 | First | 0 | 30 |
| Project 3 | First | 0 | 30 |
| Auto | Project 1 | 16 | 16 |
| Huis | Project 1 | 14 | 14 |
| Auto | Project 2 | 11 | 11 |
| Huis | Project 2 | 12 | 12 |
| Overig | Project 2 | 7 | 7 |
| Auto | Project 3 | 30 | 30 |

Comment: Bonus points if you can also create a column representing the relative percentages.

Comment: This was not part of your initial quesiton. Please be fair.

Answer (score 2):

You could approach this form a graph perspective, using [`networkx`](https://networkx.org):

```
import networkx as nx

# create the graph
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df.replace('', None).dropna(subset=['child', 'parent']),
                            source='parent', target='child',
                            edge_attr='value', create_using=nx.DiGraph)

# get the descendents edge value
total = {}
for n in nx.dfs_postorder_nodes(G):
    for e in G.out_edges(n, data=True):
        # add
        total[n] = total.get(n, 0) + total.get(e[1], 0) + e[2]['value']

# map values to original DataFrame
df['total'] = df['child'].map(total).fillna(df['value'], downcast='infer')
```

Alternative loop:

```
total = {}
for n in nx.dfs_postorder_nodes(G):
    total[n] = sum(total.get(e[1], 0) + e[2]['value']
                   for e in G.out_edges(n, data=True))

df['total'] = df['child'].map(total).add(df['value'], fill_value=0)
```

Output:

```
       child     parent  value  total
0      First                 0     90
1  Project 1      First      0     30
2  Project 2      First      0     30
3  Project 3      First      0     30
4       Auto  Project 1     16     16
5       Huis  Project 1     14     14
6       Auto  Project 2     11     11
7       Huis  Project 2     12     12
8     Overig  Project 2      7      7
9       Auto  Project 3     30     30
```

Graph:

[image]